# Hide class by default, show that class when clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I have the class on my page .showhide to be hidden by default, but when you click on a link, the contents of .showhide are displayed?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Tried *anything*? Your question shows zero research effort.

Comment: Yes, I've tried http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_hide_show.asp but I need the element to be hidden by default and can't forget how to do that

Comment: Use CSS. `.showhide{display:none}`.

Comment: How can I make that display:none go away when someone clicks on a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions `addClass` and `removeClass` to add or remove a class to your element.

For example

```
$('#myId').addClass('myClass');
```

or

```
$('#myId').addClass('myClass');
```

where

```
.myClass { display: none; }
```

is, would add or remove the class `myClass` to an element with the id `myId`. Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GT2BM/3/).

**Update:** The fiddle is updated to remove a div with a link.

Comment: Thanks for your response, is there anyway to only add the class myClass when a link is clicked?

Comment: Updated again... look at the actual version now. If you click the link, the specified div will be removed.